# How to make <span> the same height as <input type="text">

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm trying to put a  element to the left of a  element, however I can't seem to make them the same height and align with each other. The span always seems to be positioned a little higher.

Anyone got any ideas?

Sparkles*

Edit: HTML section

```
<label for="name">Username: </label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" maxlength="15"/>
<span id="box" style="display:none"></span>
```

CSS

```
span.box{
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    margin-left:20px;
    border:1px;
    padding:2px;
    height: 16px;
}

input.name {
    width: 115px;
    height: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Please put a portion of your code, the solution varies depending on the type of tags used

Comment: If you're trying to label input fields, try the Label tag ( http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp )

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to vertically align items in the same line, you probably *don't* need to make them the same height - just give them the same value for the `vertical-align` property.

```
.myinput, .myspan {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

What a lot of people don't understand with vertical-align is that in order for things to be vertically aligned to the middle, everything in that line has to have a vertical-align property of 'middle' - not just one thing (like the span).

Imagine an invisible horizontal line running though any inline content.  Usually the baseline of text, and the bottom of images, are lined up with this line.  However, if you change vertical-align to middle, then the middle of the element (text span, image etc) is aligned with this line.  However that's not going to line up vertically with other items if they are still aligning their bottom or baseline to that line - they would need to align their middle to that line too.

Comment: wow that works! now I've just to match heights, thanks everyone! :)

Comment: Thanks for "everything in that line has to have a vertical-align property of 'middle'"..!

Comment: well heights may vary through different browsers this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try padding :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .lbl {
            background-color:lime;
            padding:0;
        }
        .t {
            height:17px;
            padding:0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="lbl">My label : </span>
    <input class="t" type="text" name="t">
</body>
```

Keep in mind 'span' is an inline element, rather than a block level element, so size definitions don't apply, **unless you use 'display:block' CSS property**. Inline elements get the size of the contents, so things like font size are what define the height of that span.

Also I'd use 'label' tag with the 'for' attribute, rather than a 'span'. This makes a better structure, and has the advantage of moving the focus to the *input* by clicking on the *label*.

The following is a block-level example, which allows pixel by pixel alignment for every browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
.lbl {
    background-color: lime;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
}
.t {
    border: 1px solid silver;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 150px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <label class="lbl">My label : </label>
    <input class="t" type="text" name="t">
</body>
```

Comment: howdy, I'm already using the <label> tag before the input, this is a hidden span which appears if an error is returned to the form. I've tried the padding, it makes it the same size but now it sits a little higher than the input box.

Comment: that's because the border of the input box. if you have a visible background or border, and trying to align pixel by pixel, then you may use it block level, as font heights may vary a little depending on the browser and the system. I'm adding a block level-example to the answer.

Comment: This is partially true. inline-block elements can also get their sizes defined

Answer (score 0):

here's an slightly retouched version of SuperDucks code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .lbl {
        background-color:lime;
        padding:0;
    line-height: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    }
    .t {
        height:17px;
        padding:0;
        height: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="lbl">My label : </span>
    <input class="t" type="text" name="t">
</body>
```

Comment: please note that inline-block is not available on IE platform. I'm a fan of inline-blocks otherwise =)

Comment: you're right, but starting with IE8, its supported, so, hopefully, someday soon, we can use it without worries

Comment: also, IE 6/7 support inline-block on inline elements, according to this, so it might work? http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: i dont' have ie, but i'd love to know, thanks for the comment

Comment: yeah, it was too late to edit the comment, I was gonna add. IE7:n/a IE8:problematic support, it begins with IE9, but we still take IE7 into account. And I hear you, I too never use IE except testing a website for it, FX is the very first software I install when installing an OS =)