# How to set the height of the input "text" and span at the same value

Tags: html, css

I have, on the same row, an input text and a span.
In firefox they don't have the same high.
To me seems that the span has a lowest height.
What is the best way to have input text and span with the same height?

```
<div class="form">
    <input type="text" required="required" class="data-item">
    <span class="add-on">Orders</span>
</div>​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BeLDD/7

P.S.:
Don't write possible duplicate of [`How to make <span> the same height as <input type=“text”>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210994/how-to-make-span-the-same-height-as-input-type-text) because I don't need things to be vertically aligned to the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall height of the input tag includes its border and padding. Unfortunately, these default values vary depending on the browser.

Explicitly set the margin, border and padding (as well as the font size) on both the span and the input using CSS until they're the desired size. Since the input has a border and your span (probably) doesn't, you'll need to make those adjustments separately based on your design.

Comment: Since it depends on the browser, should I make a different style for a different browser?

Comment: No, just explicitly set all those values. They will override any browser's defaults.

Comment: no. it does not display the same height. look at this demo, please :) http://jsfiddle.net/BeLDD/10/

Comment: and most important, be sure to set the same _font-family_ on both elements. e.g. `input, span { font-family: sans-serif; }` - the line-height could be rendered differently if you have sans & sans-serif fonts in one line.