# How to make <label> the same height as <input type=“text”>

Tags: html, css, layout

I like to give a label/span the same height as an input text field, which should be placed right next to it.

I tried to follow the recommendations from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210994/how-to-make-span-the-same-height-as-input-type-text) - but none of them worked.

I created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uoemyp5o/): it shows my overlay. But the numbers should be on the left side and NO gaps should be visible at all.

```js
var overlay = document.createElement('div');
overlay.className = "overlay";
document.body.appendChild(overlay);

var list = document.createElement('div');
var toLeft = document.createElement('span');
var toRight = document.createElement('span');

toLeft.textContent = "<";
toLeft.className = "control";

toRight.textContent = ">";
toRight.className = "control";

overlay.appendChild(list);
overlay.appendChild(toLeft);
overlay.appendChild(toRight);

// build list
var selection_history = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (var i in selection_history) {
 var label = document.createElement('label');
 label.textContent = parseInt(i) + ".";
 label.className = "list";
 
 var input = document.createElement('input');
 input.className = "comment";
 
 var br = document.createElement('br');
 
 list.appendChild(label);
 list.appendChild(input);
 list.appendChild(br);
}
```

```css
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid black;
    right: 0px;
}
.list {
    display: block;
    width: 24px;
}
.comment {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
}
.control {
    width: 50%;
}
.list, .control {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.list:hover, .control:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just float the label left? https://jsfiddle.net/uoemyp5o/2/

Answer (score 0):

try to set a left float for the list , then you can see the numbers on left side

```
.list {
 display: block;
 width: 24px;
 float:left;
}
```

Comment: I tried this before, but its not working. Please see following fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/2dqmcfcc/ - it shows huge gaps. And in my extension the elements are completely messy...